# Handling untrusted certificates

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, windows-8, certificate

We have got web service that works with certificates. When we open this link in a Web Browser we see next picture:

There is a problem with website security certificate.

And only when we click Proceed anyway it displays us needed information (response). So in our application request we also get back pictures form ( This is untrusted certificate... ) as a response. 
After searching the web we have found this:
ServicePointManager

But also we found out, that we can’t add it into our Windows market application project.

But MSDN says that:

[image]

Any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this (available in 8.1 only)
[How to ignore Self Signed Certificate errors in Windows Store apps (8.1)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/10/17/how-to-ignore-self-signed-certificate-errors-in-windows-store-apps-8-1.aspx)

Quote from the post on why only in 8.1 :

> Up until Windows 8.1 you could not do this in Windows Store apps with our HTTP classes.

Comment: But i need in Windows 8

Comment: Updated answer. They are explicit on that. They only hope i see in doing it in Win8 is the fact they point out that the limitation exists with *their HTTP classes*.